# Is this a good way to control Async in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I am writing a simple server in NodeJS without using any frameworks except database connection. I  have this code to populate database:

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
    var model = require('./model');
    var seedData = [
        // Some seed objects
    ];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < seedData.length; i++) {
        model.Complaint.createComplaint(seedData[i], function(err, id) {
            count++;
            if (count === seedData.length) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Here I check in each callback if other callbacks have been executed. If `count` is the length of `seedData` array, I call the main callback. Is it a good way to manage loop which calls async methods?

Comment: It's a good way to do it ([an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30683157/5388620)) but you should look into promises. Did you write `model.Complaint.createComplaint()`?

Comment: If `seedData.length` is large, you may well flood your database with inserts, as they are started concurrently. Also, if one function call fails, the other ones will still be executed instead of providing an early-out.

Answer (score 0):

As ShanShan already mentioned in the comment, [Promises](https://promisesaplus.com/) are really powerful when you need to work with a lot of asynchronous functions. If you're just looking to simplify your current script a bit, [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) may be useful for you. It allows you to rewrite your loop as:

```
async.each(seedData, model.Complaint.createComplaint, callback);
```

And provides a lot of other methods which give you more control over the flow (such as running the functions either in series or parallel).